# Python 3.x: Multiprocess cannot serialize 'ExFileObject' object

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I try to read txt file from the archive(tar) and process file with function. I have a lot of files and decided to use multiprocessing lib to speed up calculations. But I got error "cannot serialize 'ExFileObject' object". Below is an example of my code. 
How to serialize 'ExFileObject' object or how to speed up my calculations with multiprocessing lib? I am using Python 3.4

```
import tarfile
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def start():
    result = {}
    file_path = '...somepath'
    tar = tarfile.open(file_path, 'r')
    for file in tar:
        extr_file = tar.extractfile(file)
        p = Process(target=straight_calc, args=(extr_file, result)) #thows error
        p.start()
        p.join()
    print(result)

def straight_calc(file, result):
    content = file.readlines()
    for line in content:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: as for using multiprocessing for "speeding things up", it seems that you're actually making things worth, since you're starting *one* process and waiting for it to complete before going on. So you're still working sequentially while adding an overhead of spawning a process for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code works fine for me. I would only add a `NoneType` check because `NoneType` has no `readlines` attribute and `tar.extractfile(file)` might return a `NoneType` value.

```
import tarfile
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def start():
    result = {}
    file_path = '...somepath'
    tar = tarfile.open(file_path, 'r')
    for file in tar:
        extr_file = tar.extractfile(file)
        if extr_file is not None:
            p = Process(target=straight_calc, args=(extr_file, result))
            p.start()
            p.join()
    print(result)

def straight_calc(file, result):
    content = file.readlines()
    for line in content:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

You might try pickling your extr_file with `picklestring = pickle.dumps(extr_file)`. Pickling extr_file before executing Process should throw a more useful exception.

Comment: I tried `d = pickle.dump(extr_file, open( "save.p", "wb" ))` but it also throws error "cannot serialize 'ExFileObject' object". Also, when I call function `straight_calc(extr_file, result)` it works. So, the main problem is to call function using multiprocess (Process or other) so that to speed up calculating.

Comment: I tried your code with some text files in a tar archive. I could not reproduce "cannot serialize 'ExFileObject' object". How is your tar file organised. What type of files are you trying to read.

Comment: I put an archive on Google Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1myD5vqCbC2cm04elRZN1dPQ2M/view?usp=sharing There are folders with txt files in archive.

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: Above I wrote a code sample, indeed my `straight_calc` method is in another module. Could it throw an error? I will try to manipulate call method and will try to call the method with file parameter and then extract it. I will let you know when I have additional info.

Comment: I tried different solutions and all of them throw serialization error. FinallyI extract file, read lines and then start process `p = Process(target=straight_calc, args=(content, result))` my `straight_calc` just looping lines and makes calcs.